MemSQL (SingleStore) to S3 creates multiple zip files using Python
I am trying to fetch data from MemSQL (SingleStore) into S3 in form of parquet files. Using following query:
SELECT ...

INTO S3 file_path

CONFIG '{"region":"", "endpoint_url":"", "compatibility_mode":true, "multipart_chunk_size_mb":5}'

CREDENTIALS '{"aws_access_key_id": ""aws_secret_access_key":""}'

FORMAT PARQUET;

But it always creates 17 files in S3. How can I control count of files and corresponding size?
"multipart_chunk_size_mb" - This parameter does not seem to have any impact.

select into S3 performs a distributed select, the query is pushed down to each leaf and executed on each partition, and a separate file is written for each partition.
Currently there is no way to control number of files but if you would like to output in a single file try a group by or order by on any field
'ORDER BY, GROUP BY, etc. then the query will be run on each leaf but the result will be collected on the aggregator and then output to S3'
https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v8.7/reference/sql-reference/data-manipulation-language-dml/select/#select-into-s-3
